# How do I generate a nameless url parameter from a form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

I want to use a get form submit to generate an url that looks like:
submit.html?a&b=c

According to the w3c spec here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name-isindex
You should be able to use name="isindex" in order to generate nameless attributes. However when trying a setup like this:

```
<input type="text" name="isindex" value="a" />
<input type="text" name="b" value="c" />
```

it doesn't seem to work in chrome (works fine in safari and firefox though)

When looking at MDN there's mentioning about the html element ISINDEX being deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/isindex

but no info about the name attribute of a input element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Is the name also deprecated or is this a bug in chrome?
Is there another way to solve this issue with a standard submit or do I have to do a js workaround by modifying the href.

Comment: I would perhaps not call it a “bug” if browsers never implemented something this obscure in the first place. I doubt there is any other way to achieve this using HTML only; you will either have to use JS, or let the form submit its values the normal way, and then redirect to the desired address format server-side.

Comment: I just ran into this too. IE11 and Firefox 49 work as you want, but Chrome 55 doesn't have the special processing for the text input named "isindex".I've reported this as a bug, because it's not following the HTML 5 specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute

Comment: So did you manage to create nameless parameter in an html form? isindex does not seem to be for creating nameless parameters.